# Setting default maxLength for Grails GORM Strings?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I know you can set default constraints via the grails.gorm.default.constraints config property by name by:

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(nullable:true)
}
```

but is there a way to set it by type?  I want to default all my strings to default to maxSize:2000 (primarily to force the default db mapping to not be to varchar(255))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this easily in `Config.groovy`.  You can create a custom dialect for hibernate without too much trouble though.  For example (using the Postgres dialect):

```
 package mypackage;

 import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect;
 import java.sql.Types;

 public MyPostgresDialect extends PostgresSQLDialect {
     public MyPostgresDialect() {
         super();
         registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "text");
     }
 }
```

Then update `DataSource.groovy` to use the new dialect:

```
datasource {
    ...
    dialect = mypackage.MyPostgresDialect
}
```

Comment: That's a really good idea - I hadn't thought of that entire approach.  I have just thought that auto-binding an unlimited datatype (e.g. String) to a very short limited type (varchar(255)) is a recipie for trouble.  Heck - given that pretty much all modern databases are much smarter on space now (only use what's needed) - I am suprised varchars even have limits - why not do an upper cap of a very high value (e.g. 8k, 32k, etc), and use constraints if needed to artifically limit it... but that's just my meandering thoughts...

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide an additional answer I received from a co-worker - which wasn't applicable in this case, but might help others...

if you can follow a naming convention in your properties, then you could do a:

```
'*_s': (maxSize:2000)
```

I personally don't like cross-tying prop names and datatypes - but wanted to include this as an approach (even though I like the dialect answer by ataylor more...)