# Overriding default `maxSize` in domain class

Tags: grails, groovy, constraints, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I've set a default value, for `maxSize` constraint, to all my domains, using

```
config.grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    ...
    '*'(..., maxSize: 80)
    ...
}
```

Now, I want to override this value inside my domain class; I can do that by defining it there

```
static constraints = {
    ...
    prop maxSize: 120
    ...
}
```

**But how could I make it unlimited, for instance?**

I wish it could have been done by providing `-1`. Or the `String` and other `Collection`s could have been handled differently, by using two different `constraint`s; such as, `maxSize` or `maxLength`, or `maxSize` or `maxElems`.

Or

**Is it possible to define default `maxSize` just for `String` types, in the first place?**

**Note:** `maxSize` works for `String` and `Collection`, both. For `String`, defining unlimited `maxSize`, doesn't make much sense, due to the size limitation on database field. But `Collection`s are used for relationships, it makes perfect sense to not have any limit here.

**Edit:** Somewhat, got an answer of my second question in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19432543/42769), provided in the comment; but [1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19432976/42769), there, is a workaround and not very related to my problem, I want the `constraint`, and [2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19454624/42769) will work, but is not to my liking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432543/setting-default-maxlength-for-grails-gorm-strings