# Default string size for Postgresql and Grails 3.3.8 seems to be 20 characters

Tags: grails, grails-orm, postgresql-9.3, grails-3.3

My string columns are defaulting to 20 characters.  All the documentation suggests the default is 255.  How do I set that without changing each individual column.  I am using Grails 3.3.8 and Postgresql 9.3.

```
class DbConnection {
    String name
    String platform
```

creates 20 character columns
If I add a mapping:

```
static mapping = {
    name sqlType: 'varchar(255)'
    platform sqlType: 'varchar(255)'
    url sqlType: 'varchar(255)'
}
```

I get the proper 255 characters, however, grails fails the string on validation:

`Field error in object 'dop_etc.DbConnection' on field 'url': rejected value [localhost:5432/rbc48_fantasy]; codes [dop_etc.DbConnection.url.size.error.dop_etc.DbConnection.url,dop_etc.DbConnection.url.size.error.url,dop_etc.DbConnection.url.size.error.java.lang.String...`

There seems to be a default size set somewhere and I can't seem to find it.  Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, found the problem in some pasted code (in application.groovy)

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(nullable: true, size: 1..255)
}
```

Here's the helpful article:
[Overriding default `maxSize` in domain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481708/overriding-default-maxsize-in-domain-class)